# How to install JSLint plugin on Notepad++?

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I downloaded JSLintNPP.0.8.3 from `https://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/`
,now what I see is a .dll file and am not sure about how to install the plugin on my Notepad++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do an offline manual install without the Plugin manager.

Just locate the `plugins` dir within your NotePad++ installation and copy the dll there.

Comment: I had to create a subfolder in the plugins folder and drop the DLL in there. Using Notepad v.7.7.1. So `plugins\JSLintNpp\JSLintNpp.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Open up notepad ++, go to plugins, locate plugin manager then show plugin manager. 
A window will pop up, on the available tab type J and you should see JSLint, tick it and then press install.